# Generate a configuration file with an entry for each selection using Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, chocolatey

Based on what I pick in Inno Setup, the installer should add an entry containing package name followed by `,` into `config.ini`

And extract the right premade config files (that are stored in the installer) needed for the few specific setups into the `Config` folder.

There are plenty of programs like Chrome/Firefox which don't need any parameters or additional configs to install.

Desired `config.ini` file syntax:

```
<package1>, <package2 /X /Y /Z>, <package 3> ...
```

Etc.

Where `<packageX>` is a string value tied to the checkboxes in the installer selection menu.

After Inno Setup completes, it should run a batch file.

Bonus points: Again.. not only output the `config.ini`, BUT also extract necessary premade configs set-up for the specific program into a folder `C:/NKsetup/Config/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add each each of your packages as a component to the [`Components` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentssection). Then in the [`Files` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection), you can choose what files get installed based on the components selected. For the packages list config file, you need to code that with use of the [`WizardIsComponentSelected` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardiscomponentselected).

```
[Setup]
DefaultDirName=C:\some\path

[Types]
Name: "custom"; Description: "-"; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: "sqlserver"; Description: "Microsoft SQL server"
Name: "chrome"; Description: "Google Chrome"
Name: "firefox"; Description: "Mozilla Firefox"

[Files]
Source: "install.bat"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "common-config.ini"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "sqlserver-config.ini"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: sqlserver
Source: "browsers-config.ini"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: chrome firefox

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\install.bat"; StatusMsg: "Installing..."
```

```pascal
[Code]

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  ConfigPath: string;
  Packages: string;
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    if WizardIsComponentSelected('sqlserver') then
    begin
      Packages := Packages + ',sql-server-express /X /Y /Z';
    end;
    if WizardIsComponentSelected('chrome') then
    begin
      Packages := Packages + ',chrome';
    end;
    if WizardIsComponentSelected('firefox') then
    begin
      Packages := Packages + ',firefox';
    end;

    // Remove the leading comma
    if Packages <> '' then
    begin
      Delete(Packages, 1, 1);
    end;

    ConfigPath := ExpandConstant('{app}\config.ini');
    // This is not Unicode-safe
    if not SaveStringToFile(ConfigPath, Packages, False) then
    begin
      Log(Format('Error saving packages to %s', [ConfigPath]));
    end
      else
    begin
      Log(Format('Packages saved to %s: %s', [ConfigPath, Packages]));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I didn't knew how to bite the topic with coding in the InnoSetup installer    But now that you showed me, that's pretty nice and easy.  Cheers !